# css animation trying to achieve in canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to achieve same kind of animation in my canvas...
can you guys tell me how to achieve it with text inside the circle in canvas...
since webkit doesnot work in firefox or ie...so i am using canvas
providing my code below...

```
 function animate(current) {
     context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     context.beginPath();
     context.arc(x, y, radius, -(quart), ((circ) * current) - quart, false);
     context.stroke();
     curPerc++;
     if (curPerc < endPercent) {
         requestAnimationFrame(function () {
             animate(curPerc / 100)
         });
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your question is vague. DO you want a duplicate in pure css?

Comment: @NickySmits: i am trying to achive same animation in canvas since webkit animation doesnt work in ie or canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got it work with the following code:

```
var SIZE = 300; 
var SPINNER_WIDTH = 30;
var STEP_PERCENT = 1;
var STEP_DELAY = 20;

var radius, centerX, centerY;
radius = centerX = centerY = SIZE / 2;

var deg360 = Math.PI * 2;
var degStart = -Math.PI / 2;

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = canvas.height = SIZE;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var percent = 0;

var animate = function() {
    ctx.width = ctx.width;    //clear canvas hack

    percent += STEP_PERCENT;
    var deg = percent / 100 * deg360;

    drawArc('#aaa', radius, deg360);    //gray backgound circle
    drawArc('#0e728e', radius, deg);    //blue spinner
    drawArc('#fff', radius - SPINNER_WIDTH, deg360);    //white center

    if (percent >= 100) {
        document.getElementById('text').innerText = 'FINISHED';
    } else {
        setTimeout(animate, STEP_DELAY);
    }
}

var drawArc = function(color, arcRadius, deg) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, arcRadius, degStart, degStart + deg, false);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY);
    ctx.fill();
}

animate();
```

You might want to play with `SIZE`, `SPINNER_WIDTH`, `STEP_PERCENT`, and `STEP_DELAY` pseudo-constants.

### Working example on jsFiddle

**Edit:**

[Here is jsFiddle of infinite animation](http://jsfiddle.net/QhfVg/2/)

**Edit 2:**

The main part of this example is these lines of code:

```
drawArc('#aaa', radius, deg360);
drawArc('#0e728e', radius, deg);
drawArc('#fff', radius - SPINNER_WIDTH, deg360);
```

First we draw grey background circle, then blue arc (where `deg` is current degree), and finally we cut out a center (initially our arcs are solid). These arcs are some kind of layers, one above the other.

If you want to make a semicircle with another color, you may play with `drawArc` calls. For example you may paste this code between first and second lines:

```
var rightColor = 'green';
drawArc(rightColor, radius, deg360 / 2);
```

Take a look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QhfVg/3/)

Comment: thanks for your reply...i am trying to achieve another segment with different color...when the blue color reaches semicircle...even i have updated an image...dont know how to use two different colors for the same round

Comment: but in between the segments they are using the same blue as background to show the difference between the segments....can you pls tell how to achieve it...thank u so much for explaining  your code...updated my image

Comment: @user3299657 Take a look at this - http://jsfiddle.net/QhfVg/4/ Feel free to ask me if it's not exactly what you want :)

Comment: but we are missing dark blue color...and the segments should not be grey...it should be light blue color...thanks for your help...

Comment: I'm a bit confused :) what color should be attached to percentage? The dark blue one or light blue?

Comment: i have updated the image...the circle border first is grey...then it starts with light blue...then each segment changes into dark blue....and space between segments is light blue....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49323/discussion-between-zub-and-user3299657)